# Rails: Why pluck method doesn't work while try to send out data as csv?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've tried to fix performance while generating csv file with Rails application. The total of data around 24000 data. I'm trying to use `pluck` method in here, but it doesn't show up. Before I change to `pluck`, it was using `find_each` method. The code before I change was:

```
data = CSV.generate do |csv|
  csv << header_column # name of header csv files
  Class.includes(:other_class).find_each do |user|
    csv << [
      user.id,
      user.name,
      user.email,
      etc
    ]
  end
end
```

The code above works fine, but given generate files so long a few minutes to generate 24000 data. Then I change with pluck by changing the `find_each` with `pluck`, then it didn't show any data. I also check in console it return empty value which is actually they selecting data from Class?

**Update**

Schema Members:

```
create_table "members", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "email"
  t.string   "name"
  t.string   "phone_number"
  t.string   "nationality"
  etc related information as member
end
```

Schema Investor:

```
create_table "investors", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "member_id"
  t.string   "approval_status"
  t.string   "company_registry"
  t.string   "director_registry"
  t.string   "bank_name"
  etc related information as investor
end
```

Schema Wallets:

```
create_table "wallets", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "investor_id"
  t.integer  "currency_id"
  t.datetime "created_at",          null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",          null: false
  t.index ["currency_id"], name: "index_wallets_on_currency_id", using: :btree
  t.index ["investor_id"], name: "index_wallets_on_investor_id", using: :btree
end
```

Schema Currency:

```
create_table "currencies", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "code"
  t.string   "symbol"
  t.decimal  "exchange_rate", precision: 12, scale: 4
  t.datetime "created_at",                             null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",                             null: false
end
```

Comment: What Rails version? What code did you actually use with `pluck`?

Comment: Unlike `find_each`, `pluck` returns just the values as a nested array. And I don't think it takes a block. With many records, you might want to combine `pluck` and `in_batches`.

Comment: @mudasobwa The rails version is 5.0.6. The code like below
Class.includes(:other_class).pluck do |user|
    csv << [
      user.id,
      user.name,
      user.email,
      etc
    ]
end

Comment: @Stefan is the in_batches with the value as parameter do u mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all - `pluck` does not accept blocks.

Can you try this:

```
data = CSV.generate do |csv|
  csv << header_column # name of header csv files
  Class.includes(:other_class).pluck(:id, :name, :email).each do |row|
    csv << row
  end
end
```

`Class.includes(:other_class).pluck(:id, :name, :email)` returns array of arrays where each of them contains:
- id
- name
- email

of the `Class` objects. If you would like to get data from `other_class`, then use: `'other_class.id'` (as a `pluck` method argument)

Comment: "pluck seems to expect symbols" - I have to disagree, you can pass a string as an argument.

Comment: That's because when I checked my answer before submitting it, I treated backquotes as quotes :)

Comment: Thanks, this is work. What if I want to get data by foreign key inside Class or other_class. Example I have wallet_id inside Class or other_class, can I also get the data with 'other_class.wallets.euro.balance'?

Comment: I've tried to use 'other_class.id', with `Class.includes(:other_class).pluck(:id, :name, :email, 'other_class.account_number')` how exactly implement that? In :other_class let say I put wallets as foreign key and class_id, but failed to call that. In the previous code it build by using `Class.includes(:other_class).find_each do |user| user.wallets.euro.balance end`

Comment: Can you please add your database schema? It will be good to take a look at it before replying to your question.

Comment: Yes, I already update my question. For the "user.wallets.euro.balance" in here we create module as accessor method in investor_accessor.rb to access "balance". The "euro" actually called from currencies.code but we make method again inside model currency.rb. The apps I handle already have much tables in the schema already 2000 lines, so I just add a few tables related to speed up the download report. Thanks for your help before.

Comment: Probably it might be really hard to get those values. `pluck` fetches data from the database, without involving methods from your models. I think you will need to pass all your models to `includes` and then fetch the data.

Comment: Okay bro, really thanks for your help and explanation :). I'll do some testing again for that.